# Why doesn't equals throw NullPointerException when one of the variables is pointing to null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Let's consider following code:

```
String s1=null;
String s2="something";
System.out.println(s2.equals(s1));
//output: false
```

Why is `s2.equals(s1)` not throwing `NullPointerException`?

EDIT: Thanks for the Answers, I am sorry for the Question I wasn't aware of this

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return
>   false.

The confusion came because toString method was throwing exception while equals didn't and I thought to myself but equals has also to "look" inside of the object so that it can perform comparison why isn't equals also throwing excetion

Comment: That's because the `equals` method in the `String` class won't de-reference `s1` if it's null.

Comment: Because s2 isn't null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the contract for the `equals` method, as specified in the Javadoc for the Object.equals method , explicitly states:

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

If the method threw a NullPointerException, it would be non-compliant with the contract.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the equals implementation has something like:

`if ( o == null ) return false;`

So, why would you expect this to throw an NPE? If you want it to throw one, change your statement to:

```
System.out.println( s1.equals(s2));
```

Then, you are actually calling an instance method on a null without checking for null first.